# Find the Nth instance of a character in Excel (no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

TL;DR summary: I want a formula that will find the Nth "`_`" (for any N) in a string, and return its index; OR to find the Nth substring, separated by "`_`". I have VBA to do this, but it's slow.

Long version:
I am working with advertising campaign data. My marketers (fortunately) use a consistent naming scheme for their campaigns. Unfortunately, it's very long.

The campaign names contain exactly 1 piece of data that I cannot otherwise get from reports.

For reference, campaign names are of the format:

```
ADV_CO_BG_Product_UniqueID_XX_mm.dd.yyyy_mm.dd.yyyy_TYP_NUM
```

... and I have a column of about 200K of them (growing by a couple hundred each week).

Edit:
The important part is that there are multiple parts of the campaign name, with `_` as a delimiter between them. In this case, I want the 9th part, but i want an option that is flexible enough that I don't have to add or remove lines to change which part I target.

I've seen on other questions to use a nested formula like:

```
=MID(
  Data_OLV[@Campaign],
  FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],
    FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],
      FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],
        FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],
          FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],
            FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],
              FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],
                FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign])+1)
              +1)
            +1)
          +1)
        +1)
      +1)
    +1)
  +1,
3)
```

... but that is hard to modify if I need something in a different position.

I have a UDF called StringSplit (see below) that provides the desired results, but it's extremely slow (and only works if you enable macros, which not all of my audience does).

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

```vb
    Public Function StringSplit(input_ As String, delimiter_ As String, index_ As Integer)
        On Error GoTo err

        out = Split(input_, delimiter_, -1, vbTextCompare)
        StringSplit = out(index_ - 1)
        Exit Function
    err:
        If err.Number = 9 Then
            StringSplit = CVErr(xlErrRef)
            Exit Function
        End If
        StringSplit = err.Description
    End Function
```

Comment: Are they carriage returns at the end, you could try along these lines `split(split(strInput,"[typ]")(1),chr(10))(0)`

Comment: "but that seems a bit absurd". But if it works, does that matter? :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav My Excel doesn't recognize "split()" as a worksheet function... is that VBA?

Comment: @TimStack It's more about being able to choose an arbitrary number, rather than pasting in `FIND("_",Data_OLV[@Campaign],` to the middle of a formula (or deleting it).

Comment: Here you can find an answer to your question: https://exceljet.net/formula/find-nth-occurrence-of-character

Comment: Yes, it is, you can wrap it in a function passing the argument so `public function fnSplitfunction(strInput) as string` then put the code in there.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav OP did request the answer to be non-VBA though

Comment: Sorry, I only had the VBA filter on my search, and this was in it then, presumably changed since, and saw the code in the post.

Comment: IS the data in a single cell?  Or is each line on a separate row?  And WHAT VERSION of Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Data is in consecutive rows, always in the same column. The entire string fits in a single cell.

Comment: And the only common character in all your data is " " and you need to find the value between the " "?

Comment: @ImtiazAhmed "`_`" (underscore), not " " (space). Not the ONLY common character, but it is the delimiter.

Comment: I'm really confused now. So after your edit causing confusion, which one would be the data example? The 1 line one? The multiple lines one? 1 single cell? Several cells? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I hope that makes more sense! I have a column of campaign names (1 per row) that look like `ADV_CO_BG_Product_UniqueID_XX_mm.dd.yyyy_mm.dd.yyyy_TYP_NUM`

Comment: I had a complete formula with `ADV_CO_BG_Product_UniqueID_XX_mm.dd.yyyy_mm.dd.yyyy_TYP_NUM  
ADV: Advertiser (Abbreviated)  
CO: Country (2 letter code)  
BG: Business (2- or 3-letter code)  
Product: Product Line (arbitrary string)  
UniqueID: structured text (variable length)  
XX: 2-letter code  
mm.dd.yyyy: Start / End of campaign
TYP: The type of advertisment  
NUM: An internal identifier for a specific advertiser (not always present)` and now I see i wasted my time. So you want to get the text between the last two underscores (if NUM is present) or last one (no NUM present)

Comment: The formula I posted can help you to a certain extent as you don't need to modify the formula, but change the `Nth instance` value and you can also change the `delimiter type` if required. The drawback of this formula is if the `Nth instance` changes, you have to manually count it and change the value.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the formula you are looking for -

```
=MID(A2, FIND(CHAR(1), SUBSTITUTE(A2, B2, CHAR(1), C2))+1, FIND(CHAR(1), SUBSTITUTE(A2, B2, CHAR(1), C2+1)) -  FIND(CHAR(1), SUBSTITUTE(A2, B2, CHAR(1), C2))-1)
```

This is how to do it -

[image]

Here `B2` is the `Delimiter type` and `C2` is the `Nth occurrence of the Delimiter`. you can modify the code as per your need. Just change the `B2` & `C2`.

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, you want to locate the **third** instance of **?** in cell **A1**, try:

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?",CHAR(1),3))
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

We assume that `CHAR(1)` does not appear in the original string.
To get the **last** instance, use:

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?",CHAR(1),(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?","")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying, if I am correct, that the data you receive is always in format you posted and that you consistently want to extract the TYP data.

Why not search for `TYP` in the string, and additionally search for `NUM` as that indicates the following subdata?

Then, you would end up with a formula such as

```
=TRIM(MID(W20,SEARCH("TYP",W20),SEARCH("NUM",W20)-SEARCH("TYP",W20)))
```

In this formula, cell `W20` holds the entire data-string. Naturally you can edit this range or instead paste the whole string in its place.

**EDIT**

Since OP mentioned the title strings are not consistent:

```
=TRIM(MID(W20,SEARCH(A1,W20),IF(A2="",LEN(W20),SEARCH(A2,W20)-SEARCH(A1,W20))))
```

In cell `A1` would be the title string of the data that has to be extracted, in this case being `TYP`

In cell `A2` would be the title string of the next subdata. If empty, the formula returns all characters found from the first `SEARCH` function using cell `A1`.

Comment: I am not sure whether they would be in the same order, so not sure searching for NUM would work, @farfromunique, could you clarify, as this will help.

Comment: They are always in the same order, but the text "TYP" isn't always there -- it can be (for instance) "OLV", "GDN", "Banner", "TVC", or others. Also, NUM is not always present.

Comment: So perhaps it would be a sound choice to place the 'titles', so to say, which need to be searched for in two separate cells and refer to those instead of the strings as I wrote it now? That way you'd be able to search dynamically with just a little user input.

Comment: @Farfromunique Ok, TYP can change, and NUM is not always present, but order is always the same. If NUM is not present, is there any other tag after TYP? or TYP would be the last one if there is no NUM?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns If NUM is not present, then TYP is the end of the string

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns for my formula, that would not matter. If a value in `A2` is omitted, the formula would still produce a correct result

Comment: @Farfromunique I have edited my formula, have you tried it?

Comment: @TimStack I figured out what was confusing in my original post, and edited it. The string I'm searching doesn't have the descriptors below it.

Comment: Oh, that changes everything

Answer (score 0):

As Egan Wolf commented, there is a solution at http://exceljet.net/formula/find-nth-occurrence-of-character
`=MID([@[Campaign]],FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE([@[Campaign]],"_",CHAR(160),9))+1,4)`

Or, more generally:
`=MID(TextToSearch,FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(TextToSearch,Delimiter,CHAR(160),InstanceNumber ))+1,LengthOfDesiredSection)`

`LengthOfDesiredSection` can, of course, by found with a subsection of the first formula, like so (line breaks added for clarity):

```
  =MID(TextToSearch,
   FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(TextToSearch,Delimiter,CHAR(160),InstanceNumber))+1,
   IFERROR(
  (FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(TextToSearch,Delimiter,CHAR(160),InstanceNumber+1)-
   FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(TextToSearch,Delimiter,CHAR(160),InstanceNumber)))-1,
   LEN(TextToSearch)-
   FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(TextToSearch,Delimiter,CHAR(160),InstanceNumber))))
```

The `IFERROR()` protects against situations where the `Delimiter` only appears `InstanceNumber` times in the `TextToSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the nth instance of an underscore delimited string, **and return that sub-string**, is with this formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),MAX(1,999*(n-1)),999))
```

where `n` is the instance you are looking for.

But, of course, this requires that the elements are present in the same order, and are always present (or replaced by an underscore if they are not).

If you are using a version of Excel with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),n)
```

Not sure which one would be more efficient (faster) on a large database