# Splitting names given in single cells without using text to column excel

Tags: excel-formula, split

i want to use excel formula to split multiple names given in a single cell. dont want to use text to column feature. For example

[image]

in the above yellow is the variable name & the green color is the required format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [find the nth instance of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374800/find-the-nth-instance-of-a-character-in-excel-no-vba): `FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(string,delimiter,CHAR(1),nth))`. For the first, we use `LEFT(string,position_first-1)`. For the last: `RIGHT(string,LEN(string)-position_last)`. For all in between: `MID(string,position_first+1,position_second-position_first-1)`.

So, combining the logic, we may get this:
`=IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(B$1=1,LEFT($A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/",CHAR(1),1),1)-1),MID($A2,FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/",CHAR(160),B$1-1),1)+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/",CHAR(1),1+B$1-1),1)-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/",CHAR(1),B$1-1),1)-1)),RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/",CHAR(1),B$1-1),1))),"")`

`IFERROR(...,"")` is used to return "" after last occurrence (below, in G2). Nested `IFERROR(... RIGHT)` will be triggered at last occurrence (since `MID` will fail there; below at F2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

With the full name in cell A2, the formulas go as follows:

Get the first name:

```
=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)
```

Get the last name:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1))
```

You enter the formulas in cells B2 and C2, respectively, and drag the fill handle to copy the formulas down the columns. The result will look something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, however in my case i have multiple names in the cell, separated by "/". the formula mentioned will only work for single name.